# .html(""), .empty("") not working in IE

Tags: asp.net

Guys I am fed up trying to empty the contents of a div at run time in IE!!
I simply need to empty the contents of a div, because every time I need to show a new video like youtube.

I tried everything like `$('#divvideo').empty("")`, `$('#divvideo').remove()` but nothing works for me in IE. could you please suggest what can I do??

```
 $('#divvideo').html("");
        this.$Embed = $('<embed></embed>');
        this.$Embed.attr({ src: src.href });
        this.$Embed.attr({ width: "420" });
        this.$Embed.attr({ height: "366" });
        this.$Embed.attr({ type: "video/x-ms-wmv-plugin" });
        this.$Embed.attr({ pluginurl: "http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia"    });
        this.$Embed.attr({ allowchangedisplaysize: "1" });
        this.$Embed.attr({ autosize: "1" });
        this.$Embed.attr({ displaysize: "1" });
        this.$Embed.attr({ showcontrols: "1" });
        this.$Embed.attr({ showstatusbar: "1" });
        this.$Embed.attr({ autorewind: "1" });
        this.$Embed.attr({ autostart: "1" });
        $('#divvideo').append(this.$Embed);
```

Comment: what happens if you do .html('').empty().remove() all at once?

Comment: A friend of mine also has problems with removing a flash player in IE. He had to resort to a work-around. Sadly I don't know the work-around. I think it is a `<div>` overlaid or made invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply solve this with little code like this.

```
        var divid = document.getElementById("video");
        if (divid.innerHTML) 
        {
            org = divid.innerHTML;
            divid.innerHTML = '';
            divid.innerHTML = org;
        }
        var vdobj = "<object width='425' height='350'><param name='movie' value='" + src.href + "'></param><param name='wmode' value='transparent'></param><embed src='" + src.href + "' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' wmode='transparent'  width='425' height='350'></embed></object>";
        divid.innerHTML = vdobj;
        return false;
```

I was missing a check of if (divid.innerHTML) for reseting video :). Thanks for your help!!
http://shankard.com/asp-net/showing-video-treeview-onclick/

Answer (score 1):

Need to see the markup to fully know the issue, I suspect theres something else going on, such as an incorrect selector. What kind of error do you get? What about using the following ?

```
document.getElementById("divvideo").innerHTML = "";
```

If you get an error like the following

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Then you're using an incorrect selector. The div's id is something else.

Comment: no Loktar am not getting any error, it simply does not work in IE. and embed tag and videos with extension .wmv don't work in other browsers so the there is problem :(!!

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery expert here, but are you sure that's not supposed to be:

```
$('div.video').html();
```

?

See http://api.jquery.com/html/ for details.

In pure JS, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myDiv='nameOfDiv';
   var somediv=document.getElementById(myDiv);
   somediv.innerHTML='';
</script>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I tried exactly your suggested code but it did not work,
when I click the link the div contents disappear but videos keeps on playing, the embed tag remains there.

Comment: Well, you might try adding an id to the embed tag and making it go away as well?  If "someid.innerHTML=''" doesn't work, you could try "someid.style.display=none", I guess. ?